# Excel cell and present date format - Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

After setting a custom date format in cell -> for example 'dd/MM/yyyy', I realized that after twice click in cell, date is present with different format, based on locale.

```
XSSFCellStyle cs = cell.getCellStyle();
XSSFDataFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat();
cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Cell format is different than it is present

[image: Cell format]

Can I somehow programmatically set this date always in specific format?

Comment: but I need sort functionality by this column with date data type, also when I provide the ' then this sign is presented with value for example '24/04/2017

Comment: @PDave you could do this with excel formula

Comment: can You provide some example formula for column that always will have date format type and strict format, thanks

Comment: What I did is, I convert the date format in java and I write it as a string cell and it works for me always.

Comment: Yes but then try to sort those strings, it's not sorted like date but like string and I need the second option